# Two dropdowns in one view, second dependent on what is selected on first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, html-select

Just started messing around with MVC and have been trying to accomplish this by looking at this example:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1670552.aspx

I keep getting this error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Line 9:  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post, new{id = "ID"})){
>   Line 10: @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.id, new SelectList(Model.list, "id","name"),"selectThis")
>   Line 11: }

Here is the code:

Model classes (stupid names, I know):

These are in a console application used only to store models.

```
namespace Model
{
  public class Model
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
  }

  public class List
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
  }

  public class subModel
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int modId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
  }

  public class subList
  {
    public List<subModel> list = new List<subModel>();
  }
}
```

Controller: (was populating subList.list and List.list with methods in the class, but decided to try it this way now, was getting the same error)

```
namespace DropboxTest.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Model/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LoadModel();
        return View();
    }

    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "id")]Model.Model model)
    {
        var modId = Request["id"];
        LoadModel();
        LoadSubCategory(Convert.ToInt32(modId));

        return View();
    }

    public void LoadModel()
    {
        Model.List listM = new Model.List();
        listM.id = 0;
        Model.Model mod1 = new Model.Model();
        mod1.id = 1;
        mod1.name = "me";
        Model.Model mod2 = new Model.Model();
        mod2.id = 2;
        mod2.name = "me";
        listM.list.Add(mod1);
        listM.list.Add(mod2);

        ViewBag.Model = listM;
    }

    public void LoadSubCategory(int id)
    {
        Model.subList subList = new Model.subList();

        Model.subModel sub1 = new Model.subModel();
        Model.subModel sub2 = new Model.subModel();
        sub1.id = 1;
        sub1.name = "notme";
        sub1.modId = 1;
        sub2.id = 1;
        sub2.name = "notme";
        sub2.modId = 1;
        subList.list.Add(sub1);
        subList.list.Add(sub2);

        List<Model.subModel> sel = new List<Model.subModel>();
        foreach (var item in subList.list)
        {
            if (item.modId == id)
            {
                sel.Add(item);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.SubModel = sel;
    }
}
}
```

View: (I have no idea if anything for subModel dropdown is working as I haven't even gotten to that part yet, but w/e.)

```
@model Model.List
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post, new{id = "ID"})){
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.id, new SelectList(Model.list, "id","name"),"selectThis")
}

@if (ViewBag.SubModel != null)
{
   @Html.DropDownList("SubModel",ViewBag.SubModel as SelectList, "select one")
}
```

It's probably something really stupid but I've been stuck for a couple of hours trying different things.

PS: This is just a test app. After I see how it is done I will be doing one with and SQL DB, using models in ConsoleApplications to retrieve and store data from the DB and display it in views, so any advice on that will be also appreciated.

A big thank you to all that have read up to here and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass a model to the view in the controller, you just store in `ViewBag.Model`.

Try something as follows:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "id")]Model.Model model)
{
    var modId = Request["id"];

    //get model
    var model = LoadModel();

    //pass it to the view
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't even get to that part of the code.
I get the error after the first 'Index' 'ActionResult' when the view loads for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stupid. Managed to fix it like you said. Just added 
return(ViewBag.Model) to the first ActionResult. Thanks very much. 
Now I have to see how to call the second ActionResult to update the second dropdown. Cheers.